# .NET two packages with same name beginning in class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am having problem using two packages with same name beginning in class.

[image: Packages]

In class

[image: In class]

My .csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.14">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.10" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.FromSqlRaw is not recognized

```
var books = _context.wnag
.FromSqlRaw<wnag>("EXEC Wnag_InsertFromXml @OrderNumber = {0}", wnag.WnagOrderNumber)
.ToList();
```

Error I get

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'DbSet<wnag>' does not contain a definition for 'FromSqlRaw' and no accessible 
extension method 'FromSqlRaw' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<wnag>' could be found (are 
you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Project  
xyzwnagsController.cs   168 Active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FromSqlRaw` extension method was introduced in EF Core 3.0. In version 2.1, there are two overloads of the `FromSql` method that correspond to the new `FromSqlRaw` and `FromSqlInterpolated` methods.

Comment: First of all you should go in your nuget package  and check whether you have this library installed and is there any update coming because you package is not installed of that version which is being showed in the .csproj file.try to   'install Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational -Version 3.1.4' and try to run.